# Reverse a sentence using StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, reverse

The below code I used string as result and just reverse sentence for example input: " the   sky is blue " and I get output:"blue is sky the". How I can use SpringBuilder instead String and then how I can reverse sentence and also words? example input: " the   sky is blue " and I want this output "eulb is yks eht"
Please help me to modify the below code.

```
public String reverseWords(String s) {
    
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    String result = "";
    while(s.length()>i){
        
        while(s.length()>i && s.charAt(i)==' '){
            i++;
        }
        if(i>=s.length()) break;   
        
        j = i;
        while(s.length()>j && s.charAt(j)!=' '){
            j++;
        }

        
        String word = s.substring(i,j);
        result = word+" "+result;
      
        
        i = j;
    }
    return result.trim();
}
```

Comment: I want to use only one space between words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `StringBuilder` as follows:

```
String str = " the  sky  is  blue ";
str = str.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.trim());
System.out.println(sb.reverse().toString());
```

Output:

```
eulb si yks eht
```

Comment: If I want one space between words

Comment: @ehsanhosseini please explain more

Comment: if between two words they are more than one space but in output I want only one space between words

Comment: Thank you Majed.